# Freelancer attending a conference in Germany, what visa type and what documents are needed?

Tags: paperwork, germany, schengen-visas, applications, moroccan-citizens

I'm working as a freelancer and making good money but without official documents from the government as freelancing activity has not legalized title here in Morocco.

I just got a ticket for WordCamp Europe 2019 with a letter of invitation. Now I want to apply for a visa but don't really know how to approach, I looked on their website and there are specific documents for each job, but mine isn't included. So, my question are:

- What type of visa should I request?
- What documents do I need for my request to be approved?
- Do I even have a chance?

Comment: Are you planning on attending as a tourist or working?

Comment: If you are not a diplomat, you do not usually need official document from your government: for press, you need it from a press association, if you are a teacher, from a university, etc. "Titles" gives very few information. Bank account and tax documents are good way and "enough" official. In any case "freelancer" is not a real job. Are you a freelancer journalist? A freelancer consultant? A freelancer programmer? A freelancer trader? There are many different freelancer jobs (and very frequents).

Comment: I'm a freelance web developer, attending this conference as part of the WordPress community to discuss the future of the platform and how to improve...etc

Comment: So your job is web developer - maybe under developer, maybe under software, maybe coder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only visa type that makes sense for this is a *uniform short-stay Schengen visa*.

The Schengen area does not distinguish between "business" and "tourism" visas, so you don't need to worry about getting a wrong kind of visa. The application form does at one point ask you to describe the *purpose* of your visit among several options that include "business" and "tourism" among others, but that is not because it will lead to different kinds of visas being issued. It is just to give the examiner an overall idea of the kind of story you're telling with your application. The important thing is that it is clear from the *totality* of your application which kind of visit it is you're proposing; they're not going to refuse a visa because they think a single question should have been answered differently.

If the conference is related to your livelihood, it would make most sense to describe your purpose as **business**. Your supporting documentation should include a description of the conference, a link to its official website, and (unless it is bleedingly obvious) an explanation of why it is relevant for you.

You should also -- as always -- provide solid documentation for your economic and social situation in your home country, such that it is evident that you reasonably plan to return home and continue your freelance work. Unfortunately freelance work tend to be difficult to document due to being irregular income, but you'll just have to do the best you can and hope for the best.

Comment: I have another side business with the commercial documents ...etc but it's completely unrelated to what I do currently and I don't do this activity anymore, just have the papers with me for selling car parts...etc, should include that or not?